# Daily or weekly popular post

Tags: wordpress, post, widget

I would like to make separate popular post widget showing daily and weekly popular instead of showing popular post of all the time.

Here is my widget code

```
<?php $args = array(  'posts_per_page'  => $number,
'meta_key'     => 'post_views_count',
'orderby'      => 'meta_value_num',
'order'        => 'DESC',
'post_type'    => 'post',
'post_status'  => 'publish',
                                );
                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                       <article <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                                <div class="masukin-gambar">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?><span class="iamoverlay"></span>
                                </div>
                                <h3 class="widget-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </a><h4 class="kategori-kecil"><?php printf( __( '%1$s', 'karatok' ), get_the_category_list(', ') ); ?></h4>
                            <span class="hitung-populer"><?php echo korankoran_get_post_views(get_the_ID()); ?></span>
                        </article>
                    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: you are not asking a question. There are no question marks "?". You have not said what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The post_views_count is just a single count that is incremented by one on each view. Therefore there is no way of doing what you want using that piece of metadata, as there is no record of when the views occurred.

There is a plugin that does what you want. I'd advise using this, as coding your requirement yourself is probably be more effort than it's worth.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/